# Banner iAds in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I want show an `adBannerView` to my app in Swift. Here's code:

```
 func loadAds() { //Called in viewDidLoad
        adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
        adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: adBannerView.center.x, y: view.bounds.size.height    - adBannerView.frame.size.height / 2)
        adBannerView.delegate = self
        adBannerView.hidden = true
    view.addSubview(adBannerView)
}

didLoadAd() {
     adBannerView.hidden = false
}

didFailToReceiveAdWithError() {
    adBannerView.hidden = true
}
```

Note that I included the iAd framework! [image]

I want it to show a banner iAd, and to not show the `adBannerView` when it doesn't recieve an iAd. On all the lines of func loadAds, I get

```
"Use of unresolved identifier 'adBannerView'"
```

And at the beginning of didLoadAd, I get

```
 "Expected Declaration"
```

Here's a look: [image]
How can I show banner iAds properly in swift?

Comment: Where do you declare "adBannerView", you have to store the variable as a class attribut

Comment: @DavidAnsermot I didn't - I thought the framework handled that. Can you post an answer showing how to declare it? Thanks!!!

Comment: what about the missing `func` keyword...?

Comment: Sorry, left those out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to declare an attribute of the class :

```
class ExampleClass {
    var adBannerView : ADBannerView
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html

Then in your code use `self.adBannerView`

Comment: Do I have to rename ExampleClass anything, or just put it in above the code in my question?

Comment: No, the exampleclass is just to show a class, the exampleClass is you viewController class. Just put at start of your class `var adBannerView : GADBannerView`

Comment: I get "Use of undeclared type 'GADBannerView'"

Comment: hmm... Still getting "Use of undeclared type ADBannerView"

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the following line at the top of your Swift file

```
import iAd
```